# Step Filter Icons Are "Greyed Out" (deactivated)

Tags: aptana

Right up front:  I am new to Aptana Studio 3 and am still exploring how to use.  Most recently,
I downloaded and installed it and right off the bat,  I noticed that the Step filters are shown as being "greyed out"  (deactivated).  I have read many, many Google postings put up by others who have experienced the same problems and I have read every FAQ I can find  and I have tried to implement the "fixes" that I found in the postings.  So far, nothing has worked and I am left not being able to use these critical Step filters.  I would appreciate any and all comments and suggestions which might help me to discover how to turn on/activate these step filters.

Baseline information:

Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.2.201208201020
Build: jenkins-studio3-rcp-master-210 (origin/master)
Date: 20 August 2012, 10:22:09
Firebug 1.11.0 installed
Operating system used:  MS Windows 7 Enterprise  version 6.1.7601 Service Pack Build 7601

What I have tried thus far:

(1)  Create break points in the javascript being tested
(2)  Made sure that the Debug view is activated  (Windows--Show View--Debug)
(3)  Run Debug

Console messages:

firebug.main; Extension: [object Object] EXCEPTION TypeError: Extension is undefined (/content/moduleConfig.js:130)
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. (/content/orion.js:3408)
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. (/content/panel.html:378)
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. (/content/panel.html:378)
Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. (/content/panel.html:378)
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. (/content/chrome/tabContext.js:589)

Thanks to all!

Rob